# How do I incorporate a "matching feature" in rails activerecord relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, self-join

I am currently working on a project that is similar to dating apps like Tinder. A user (named Owner in my program) swipes on other owners and if they both swipe on each other it creates a "match". I have been looking into finding a solution to this such as friend requests similar to Facebook friends. I am seeing people using a "confirmed" column that is boolean defaulted to false and changing it to true but I cannot figure out the logic for this. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. My only experience in this has been following or followers which doesn't require mutual requests to accomplish.

Owner class: (the user)

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :matches
    has_many :friends, :through => :matches

 end
```

Match class:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Owner"
end
```

Thank you for any help! Self joins have been a complicated topic for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more fields to your join table. You could add something like `owner_accepted` and `friend_accepted`. Although I think that just one `accepted` field is enough.
Example solution:

```
class AddAcceptedToMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :matches, :accepted, :boolean, default: false
  end
end

class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :matches
  has_many :friends, :through => :matches

  def send_request_to(friend)
    friends << friend
  end

  def accept_request_from(owner)
    matches.find_by(owner_id: owner.id).accept
  end

  def is_friends_with?(stranger)
    match = matches.find_by(friend_id: stranger.id)
    return false unless match
    match.accepted?
end

class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Owner"

  def accept
    update(accepted: true)
  end
end
```

then you can do something like:

```
owner = Owner.new
friend = Owner.new

owner.send_request_to(friend)
owner.is_friends_with?(friend)
# false
friend.accept_request_from(owner)
owner.is_friends_with?(friend)
# true
```

Comment: This got me on the right track thank you so much!